# How to delete History in terminal

Tags: 14.04

I'm new here in Linux. I'd Installed an Ubuntu and I don't know how to delete a history in Terminal. Can you help me?

Comment: history of what?

Answer (score 4):

Delete the file `.bash_history` in your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

Use **history -c** command to delete terminal history

Answer (score -1):

Enter this command

```
cat /dev/null > ~/.bash_history && history -c && exit
```

You must use `history -c` because the history will come back after re-login. The history entries have a copy in the memory and it will flush back to the file when you log out.

/dev/null is a special system file that its content is **null**. So if you throw it into `~/.bash_history`, it will completely remove the history of bash contained in `~/.bash_history`. By default, standard users of Ubuntu are set to use bash shell.

Comment: This command just outputs the content of file `/dev/null` to `~/.bash_history`

Comment: Read my updated answer.

Comment: This tutorial is similar http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-clear-bash-history/